# Grub2 unable to detect MBR disks

Tags: grub2

While adding a new SSD to my system I went to GPT / UEFI and installed new Ubuntu as well as grub2. Grub2 is working and is able to boot ubuntu/win bootmanager on this new SSD.
I'd like to boot my old system in parallel which *was* working after I enabled os_prober, but it suddenly stopped, maybe after an update / grub-mkconfig.
Grub is inserting entries for the old systems, but when its selected an error is displayed: "No such device: uid". The uid is however correct, and I can mount this partition when booting the new linux by the same UID.
The old disk is however still MBR, and when I use "ls" in grub CLI only the disk/partition which are GPT (on new SSD hd0) are listed. I tried to manually "insmod part_msdos" but still only gpt partitions shows up. I think EFI as well as AHCI could not be the issue here, but what is missing / has happened?

Comment: grub-mkconfig adds already menuentry with _insmod part_msdos_: `menuentry 'Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (22.04) (on /dev/sda1)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-b7a4f924-7d44-40a9-8cfe-dcce7ecb8aa8' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
`

Comment: I think this is something in the BIOS. If I enter and leave Setup grub finds other SATA attached disks with MBR layout. From a Reset or Power On: Only GPT on NVME are visable. Board is a Asrock B650 PG Lightning, Bios V1.24